# Debug breakpoint when EF executes SQL

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

When using SQL Server Profiler to trace the SQL queries being executed by the Entity Framework, I see some queries that just shouldn't be being executed and I can't work out which part of the code is the cause!

In Visual Studio Professional 2012, is there a way to set the debugger to break when any SQL query is executed, so I can see the call stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing (and allowed) to change the context: yes. You could put this in the context's constructor:

```
#if DEBUG

    this.Database.Log = s =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(s);
        };

#endif
```

Now you can put a breakpoint on `Debug.WriteLine(s);` and inspect the stack trace when it's hit.

You can make the breakpoint conditional to see only queries, e.g. by putting `s.Contains("[")` in the break condition.